# Pandas Dataframe return rows where state, city, and date occur multiple times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

Firstly, this is my first post, so my apologies if it is formatted poorly.

So I have this dataframe which I have attached a picture of. It contains UFO sightings and I want to return the rows where the if the city and state are the same and then also if the dates are the same. I am trying to find sightings that occurred on the same day in the same city and state. Please let me know if more info is required.
Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
# Create a column converting date_time to just date
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['occurred_date_time']).dt.normalize()

# groupby and count times where date, city and state 
# then create boolean series where count is greater than 1
m = df.groupby(['date','city','state']).transform("count") > 1

# boolean filter the dataframe rows with that series, m.
df[m]
```

Comment: I think you need `transform('count')`

Comment: @mozway, you I think you are right.   I didn't test this because no usable dataset was given.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, boolean indexing to keep the [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) rows:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['occurred_date_time']).dt.normalize()

df2 = df[df.duplicated(['date','city','state'], keep=False)]
```

If you don't want the new column:

```
df2 = df[df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df['occurred_date_time'])
                          .dt.normalize())
           .duplicated(['date','city','state'], keep=False)]
```